# D3.js zoom + pan weird behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, pan

Trying to use zoom and pan the way that is described in https://coderwall.com/p/psogia/simplest-way-to-add-zoom-pan-on-d3-js. I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="tree">
        <svg class="tree__svg" width="900" height="900"></svg>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const data = {
            "name": "node #1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "node #2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "node #4",
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "node #5"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "node #3",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "node #6",
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "node #7"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }

        const svg = d3.select(".tree__svg")
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", () =>
                svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)));

        const hierarchy = d3.hierarchy(data);

        const tree = d3.tree().size([+svg.attr("width"), +svg.attr("height")])(hierarchy);

        svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(tree.links())
            .join("path")
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "#000")
            .attr("d", d3.linkVertical()
                .x(d => d.x)
                .y(d => d.y));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I zoom out and try to pan the SVG it moves quickly outside the viewport. Even without previous zoom out panning behaves weird (the image does small jumps when it is panned).

I logged values of `d3.event.transform` and it looks like that `x` an `y` values are jumping up and down some way. The following screenshot shows what happened when I panned horizontally so only `x` values are jumping (but in fact it's strange that `y` values don't change at all). I moved the mouse smoothly so I would expect that values of `x` (and possibly `y`) increase or decrease smoothly as well. Any idea what is causing this behavior?

[image]

Comment: iirc, the element you apply transformation on should be different from the one d3 attaches listeners to when calling d3.zoom. Try changing  `svg.attr("transform, ..."` to `svg.select('g').attr("transform"`

Comment: It helped. Thanks a lot! If you write your comment as an answer I accept it.